# Firebase dynamic query depending upon the data inside an array

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

This is my dynamic array

```
let arr = [1,3];
```

I want to make number of query depending upon the length of the array

```
Firebase.database().ref(`test/${arr[0]}`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    let arr = [];
    snapshot.forEach(() => {
      arr.push({
         name: snapshot.val().name
      });
    });
    this.setState({ data: arr });
}).catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Now I am doing the query by hard coding the array index! Is there any way that I can make the query dynamic

Database structure

```
{
    "test" : {
        "1" : {
            "name" : "One",
        },
        "2" : {
            "name" : "Two",
        },
        "3": {
            "name" : "Three",
        }
    }
}
```

Desired output

Name from 1 and 3 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

```js
let arr = [1, 3];
arr.forEach((item) => {
    Firebase.database().ref(`test/${item}`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let arr = [];
        snapshot.forEach(() => {
          arr.push({
             name: snapshot.val().name
          });
        });
        this.setState({ data: arr });
    }).catch((error) => console.error(error));
});
```

Or, if you want to load call `setState` once having all data in one array:

```js
(async () => {
    let items = [1, 3];
    let arr = [];

    for (let item of items) {
        try {
            const snapshot = await Firebase.database().ref(`test/${item}`).once('value');
            snapshot.forEach(() => {
                arr.push({
                    name: snapshot.val().name
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    this.setState({data: arr});
})();
```

Comment: It's working but setting the state inside a loop is a bad idea right?? Is there any way to set that outside the forEach?

Comment: Actually, react queues many `setState` calls and execute them at once. In the end it depends on what you really want. I have added a third option in the answer, check it out.

Comment: I did the same thing that you did in your 3 option but the returned data array is always empty! Maybe a scope issue or state was set before the firebase promise??

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to wait for the promise, but I'd argue the simplest is to just use `async`/`await`. I have updated the answer (replaced the two last snippets with one new).

Comment: Marked as solved but I am getting this in my array ['One', 'One']